# Filepicker.io adds a + to files over 1 meg in size

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, filepicker

Whenever I upload a file which is over 1 meg the key that is returned has a + in it.  if it is under 1 meg I get a _.

Examples

a 10 meg file

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/3kzvwMXeTWC0_ypsVOzt

The key

2b-Oot2XQoKsXbaYHY9R+CO-OPSTrifold.pdf

a file under 1 meg

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/PsgW1m0LRyeuJcgwfPHR

The Key

XMhyGYyGQNaIy9jvnRuQ_mb10.pdf

This causes issues when I access this from my cloud front which is tied to me S3 bucket as the + is treated as a space.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Haha. Yes. So it does seem that we are inconsistent depending on what size you are using. Sorry about that. Let me see what I can do in the backend to make your life better.

Comment: That would be great.  Please let me know when it's ready to test again

Comment: Any updates on this, It would be nice to get an ETA otherwise I am going to have to disable filepicker.io uploads and to a the boring old way of uploading

Comment: Hi Chris, should be good. Pushed the code yesterday. Uses underscores.